# Ganache-cli block explorer

Tags: blocks, ganache-cli, explorers

I am working on a project and creating private blockchain network using ganache-cli. I store the blockchain in the database using --db option. I am trying to understand what is stored in each block of the blockchain. Below is the snapshot of the block.

[image]

I couldn't find the blockhash in this block. I have found another file which is named with the blockhash. Why there is no blockhash in the blockdata? What is unclehash in this block? Can we convert data of this block into human-readable data? If you know please explain some details about this block.